# Joe,pico,emacs missing

Tags: freebsd, software-installation, emacs, vi

I've installed a 'linux in a box' at home using FreeBSD and Virtual Box.But when I tryed to make a C file,joe,emacs and pico give me 'Command not found'. `joe z.c`,`emacs z.c`, `pico m.c` are the commands I've tryed.The only available editor seems to be vi,which opens a file.How can I get the other editors to work?

Comment: install by src maybe?

Comment: You have to install the other editors. See [What emacs package should I install for command line on freebsd](http://serverfault.com/questions/175057/what-emacs-package-should-i-install-for-command-line-on-freebsd) for installing emacs.

Comment: I downloaded joe from http://sourceforge.net/projects/joe-editor/ but I don't know how to add it to my virtual box.Can anyone help?

Comment: I tryed the commands found at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/joe.html but I'm getting 'Command not found'

Comment: @Matt, FreeBSD isn't a Linux distro (it is Unix), so by default it only has vi installed. See [FreeBSD Intro](http://ws.edu.isoc.org/data/2003/1867373902400b2c3583b0c/freebsd-intro.pdf) PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, FreeBSD is not Linux. There are some significant differences between the two. Now that's out of the way, on to your question.

FreeBSD ships with `ed` and `vi` in the base system. You can install other editors from ports or packages. Packages are just FreeBSD ports that have already been compiled. You can installed packages like this:

```
pkg_add -r joe
pkg_add -r emacs-nox11
```

To install from ports, you need to have the ports tree installed on your system. If the contents of 'ls /usr/ports' is not empty, ports are installed and you can update the ports tree with:

```
portsnap fetch update
```

If ports are not installed, use

```
portsnap fetch extract
```

to downloads the ports infrastructure and unpack it in `/usr/ports`.

With ports installed, you have at your fingertips a huge collection of recipes for installing software the FreeBSD way. To install `joe`, do this:

```
su -
cd /usr/ports/editors/joe
make all install clean
exit
```

Done! The ports system inspects the files in the `joe` subdirectory looking for instructions on where to find the source, how to configure and build the software, and finally, how to install it. All dependencies are downloaded and installed where necessary, and you should end up with `joe` installed and ready to run.

Emacs, being a more complex beast, has a more complex build process and can pull in all sorts of other pieces of software, such has `hal`, `X`, and many others. The FreeBSD ports system usually offers a curses-based configuration dialog in these more complex cases, so you can select which dependencies you want to include, affecting which features of the application are enabled when the install is complete. To install emacs:

```
su -
cd /usr/ports/editors/emacs
make all install clean
exit
```

It's (usually) as simple as that!

The [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/) should be considered obligatory reading, and is very useful. You will want to read Chapter 5, to get a better overview of how the ports system works.

Comment: *"First of all, FreeBSD is not Linux...."* - yeah, that immediately came to mind. He'll learn that quickly :) Principal alone probably contributed to the downvotes on his question.

Answer (score 1):

vi (or vim) is the standard editor that comes with *nix.  You will need to install other editors by yourself.

Comment: Okay,I'll try.A few months ago I used them directly without additional installations and that's why it looked unusual now.Thanks

Comment: Do you know any tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: Have not done this in a while but you should be able to get emacs from http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/ and follow the directions to install.  There may also be a prebuilt binary for your system.

Comment: Obligatory "[ed is the standard text editor](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)"

Comment: Obligatory "FreeBSD is not Linux" comment.

Comment: Oops on my part.  Changed my answer to reflect that.  Thanks.